# Doesn't show application for 7 inch tab in google play

Tags: android, google-play, tablet, multiple-apk

I created an application for Tablet 7 inch and 10 inch. After developed i added below code in manifest to show the application visible only to the tablet in Google Play.

```
<supports-screens
            android:largeScreens="true"
            android:normalScreens="false"
            android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600"
            android:smallScreens="false"
            android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

After uploaded the application is not listed for 7 inch and is listed for 10 inch tab.
When I find that application it says "It is doesn't compactable with your device" in 7 inch tab. What i needed to change to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Some of 7" tablet devices also supports **mdpi screens**, and you mentioned

```
android:normalScreens="false".
```

Please change this to

```
android:normalScreens="true"
```

and check it again.

May be this helps.

Comment: What is the resolution screen size of your 7" device?

Comment: screen size has nothing with dpi,if you want to support any dpi than add  android:anyDensity="true",also try to take a look at the uses-permission list

Comment: @RenjithKrishnan I am facing the same issue since a while. Did you get the  solution for this issue?

Comment: @AdityaKamath In my error I have a permission in manifest <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="true" /> like this. In my tablet the phone option is not availble So I chnaged it to <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
this works for me

Comment: @RenjithKrishnan Thanks for the prompt reply. I checked my manifest for that and it seems to be just fine. Can you look into the question I have posted which contains the manifest. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36592072/application-listing-for-10-inch-tablets-in-playstore-but-not-displayed-for-7-inc Any leads would be really appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Finaly I fixed the Problem. I posting the solution here:  In my error I have a permission in manifest `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="true" />` like this. In my tablet the phone option is not availble So I chnaged it to `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />`
this works for me