# Application listing for 10 inch tablets in playstore but not displayed for 7 inch tablets

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest

I have checked the uses-permission,uses-feature and support screens as suggested by other posts. I have uploaded an application in playstore as an update with the following manifest file. The previous version worked fine. The project was in eclipse earlier and is moved to android studio now.I encountered manifest merging as many libraries have been used and hence lot of permissions were added unnecessarily,hence I removed each individually. Checked the uses-permission and uses-feature too. The changes in manifest from previous version are indicated by stars

My application has to be supported only for tablets.

This is the main manifest file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        package="com.xx.yy"
        android:versionCode="13"
        android:versionName="1.8.1">

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="14"
            android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

        <supports-screens
            android:largeScreens="true"
            android:normalScreens="false"
            android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600"
            android:smallScreens="false"
            android:xlargeScreens="true"
            *tools:replace="android:normalScreens,android:smallScreens" />

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
        *<uses-feature
        *    android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"
        *    android:required="false" />

*<uses-feature
        *    android:name="android.hardware.location.network"
        *    android:required="false" />

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

        <permission
            android:name="com.xx.yy.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
            android:protectionLevel="signature" />

        <uses-permission android:name="com.xx.yy.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REORDER_TASKS" />
        *<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
     *   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>*

        *<uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS" tools:node="remove"/>
       * <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" tools:node="remove"/>
       * <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" tools:node="remove"/>
      *  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"  tools:node="remove"/>
       * <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"  tools:node="remove"/>
      *  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"  tools:node="remove"/>
    </manifest>
```

AAPT properties after running dump badging on the previous version.

```
package: name='om.xx.yyy' versionCode='8' versionName='1.7' platformBuildVersionName='5.0.1-1624448'
sdkVersion:'11'
targetSdkVersion:'19'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.INTERNET'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.CAMERA'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.WAKE_LOCK'
uses-permission: name='com.hp.wallartsolutions2.permission.C2D_MESSAGE'
uses-permission: name='com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.GET_TASKS'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.REORDER_TASKS'

application-icon-120:'res/drawable-mdpi-v4/icon.png'
application-icon-160:'res/drawable-mdpi-v4/icon.png'
application-icon-240:'res/drawable-hdpi-v4/icon.png'
application-icon-320:'res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/icon.png'
application-icon-480:'res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/icon.png'
application: label='xyz' icon='res/drawable-mdpi-v4/hp_icon.png'
launchable-activity: name='com.xx.yyy.ui.SplashScreenActivity'  label='' icon=''
feature-group: label=''
  uses-feature: name='android.hardware.camera'
  uses-feature: name='android.hardware.screen.landscape'
  uses-implied-feature: name='android.hardware.screen.landscape' reason='one or more activities have specified a landscape orientation'
  uses-feature: name='android.hardware.touchscreen'
  uses-implied-feature: name='android.hardware.touchscreen' reason='default feature for all apps'
main
other-activities
other-receivers
other-services
supports-screens: 'large' 'xlarge'
supports-any-density: 'true'
requires-smallest-width:'600'
locales: '--_--' 'ca' 'da' 'fa' 'ja' 'nb' 'id' 'be' 'de' 'he' 'af' 'bg' 'th' 'zh' 'fi' 'hi' 'vi' 'sk' 'uk' 'el' 'nl' 'pl' 'sl' 'tl' 'am' 'in' 'ko' 'ro' 'ar' 'fr' 'hr' 'sr' 'tr' 'cs' 'es' 'ms' 'it' 'lt' 'pt' 'eu' 'hu' 'ru' 'zu' 'lv' 'sv' 'iw' 'sw' 'fr-CA' 'lo-LA' 'en-GB' 'et-EE' 'ka-GE' 'km-KH' 'zh-HK' 'hy-AM' 'zh-CN' 'en-IN' 'mn-MN' 'pt-BR' 'es-ES' 'es-US' 'pt-PT' 'zh-TW' 'ms-MY'
densities: '120' '160' '240' '320' '480'
native-code: 'armeabi' 'armeabi-v7a'
```

I tried running the aapt dump badging on the current version of the apk to find the apk properties.
This is the result.

```
package: name='com.xx.yyy' versionCode='13' versionName='1.8.1' platformBuildVersionName='4.4W.2-1537038'
sdkVersion:'14'
targetSdkVersion:'19'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.INTERNET'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.CAMERA'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.WAKE_LOCK'
uses-permission: name='com.xx.yyy.permission.C2D_MESSAGE'
uses-permission: name='com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.GET_TASKS'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.REORDER_TASKS'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION'
application-label:'xyz'
application-icon-120:'res/drawable-mdpi-v4/icon.png'
application-icon-160:'res/drawable-mdpi-v4/icon.png'
application-icon-240:'res/drawable-hdpi-v4/icon.png'
application-icon-320:'res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/icon.png'
application-icon-480:'res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/icon.png'
application: label='xyz' icon='res/drawable-mdpi-v4/icon.png'
launchable-activity: name='com.xx.yy.zz.SplashScreenActivity'  label='' icon=''
feature-group: label=''
  uses-feature: name='android.hardware.camera'
  uses-feature-not-required: name='android.hardware.camera.autofocus'
  uses-feature-not-required: name='android.hardware.camera.flash'
  uses-feature-not-required: name='android.hardware.camera.front'
  uses-feature-not-required: name='android.hardware.location.gps'
  uses-feature: name='android.hardware.screen.landscape'
  uses-feature: name='android.hardware.touchscreen'
  uses-feature-not-required: name='android.hardware.wifi'
  uses-feature: name='android.hardware.location'
  uses-implied-feature: name='android.hardware.location' reason='requested android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permission, and requested android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission'
  uses-feature: name='android.hardware.location.network'
  uses-implied-feature: name='android.hardware.location.network' reason='requested android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permission'
main
other-activities
other-receivers
other-services
supports-screens: 'large' 'xlarge'
supports-any-density: 'true'
requires-smallest-width:'600'
locales: '--_--' 'ca' 'da' 'fa' 'ja' 'pa' 'ta' 'nb' 'id' 'be' 'de' 'he' 'te' 'af' 'bg' 'th' 'zh' 'fi' 'hi' 'vi' 'sk' 'uk' 'el' 'ml' 'nl' 'pl' 'sl' 'tl' 'am' 'bn' 'in' 'kn' 'ko' 'ro' 'ar' 'fr' 'hr' 'mr' 'sr' 'tr' 'cs' 'es' 'ms' 'it' 'lt' 'pt' 'eu' 'gu' 'hu' 'ru' 'zu' 'lv' 'sv' 'iw' 'sw' 'fr-CA' 'lo-LA' 'en-GB' 'et-EE' 'ka-GE' 'km-KH' 'zh-HK' 'hy-AM' 'zh-CN' 'en-IN' 'mn-MN' 'pt-BR' 'es-ES' 'es-US' 'pt-PT' 'zh-TW' 'ms-MY'
densities: '120' '160' '240' '320' '480'
native-code: 'armeabi' 'armeabi-v7a'
```

Is there something I am missing so that the application is visible for 7 inch devices too?  My application has to be supported only for tablets.
The application is not listed for any 7 inch devices.
The aapt dump badging command displays support for large and x-large devices.

Manifest merging happens due to zing library following are the permissions in the library

```
<manifest
    package="com.google.zxing.client.android"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:installLocation="auto"
    android:versionCode="94"
    android:versionName="4.5.1">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>

    <!-- Don't require camera, as this requires a rear camera. This allows it to work on the Nexus 7 -->
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.front"
        android:required="false"/>
    <!-- TODO replace above two with next line after Android 4.2 -->
    <!-- <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.any"/> -->
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
        android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash"
        android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.landscape"/>
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.wifi"
        android:required="false"/>
    <!-- This excludes Google TV, which is unfortunately included by virtue of not requiring a camera -->
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"/>
    <!-- TODO make this not required again after android.hardware.camera.any is available -->

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"/>

</manifest>
```

***UPDATE 1: I changed the  uses feature android.hardware.location.gps to false and it doesn't appear in the playstore search directly. But when searched from browser and pressing on install navigates to playstore and installs successfully. I am using a HP Slate 7 to install http://www.gsmarena.com/hp_slate_7-5317.php***

**UPDATE 2: I have changed the  uses feature android.hardware.location.network to false and uploaded a beta build. Waiting for it to be active for now**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding.

```
*<uses-feature
            android:name="android.hardware.location"
            android:required="false" />*
 <uses-feature
            android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"
            android:required="false" />

<uses-feature
            android:name="android.hardware.location.network"
            android:required="false" />
```

The HP slate 7 did not have the location support. The location block in italic is required to make the application visible in HP slate 7

Answer (score 3):

It is not matter of permission but `<support-screens>` block which causes this.

```
    <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="false"
        android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600"
        android:smallScreens="false"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        tools:replace="android:normalScreens,android:smallScreens" />
```

Yours limit your app to certain screens, so I suggest you review it, especially entries set to `false`.

**EDIT**

`tools:replace` tells that you want to use values from your manifest, not from libs'. And yours tells `normalScreen=false`. And `normalScreen` is `Traditionally this is an HVGA medium density screen, but WQVGA low density and WVGA high density are also considered to be normal`. I suspect 7" tablets you see the problem with are not hi-res screen powered, and if so that's why your app is listed as not compatible with. Unless your app is really not working on `normalScreen` there's no point of setting this to `false`.

Comment: The following set of support screen section was present in the previous build that was uploaded. The application was listed in the previous version.The current build in an update to it and the only change is the following line 'tools:replace="android:normalScreens,android:smallScreens" Does this line create a problem ? The IDE used before was eclipse and now I have migrated to Android-Studio

Comment: Makes sense. My application is targeted only for tablets. I was in a notion that normal screens are for phone only. I will change the normal screens to true and upload a beta build. Will accept the answer once it works for me. Cheers!

Comment: Detecting tablets is tricky and definitely you cannot do this that way. From other hand - why you limit usage of your app? If user's **device** got sufficient screen space for your app to show what is needed, let it run no matter it is tablet, phone or toster.

Comment: Yup agreed. But client requirement. The tablet that I tried was Asus Nexus 7 (high res 323dpi) and HP Slate 7 (170 dpi). It used to work well in the previous version

Comment: UPDATE: I changed the uses feature android.hardware.location.gps to false and it doesn't appear in the playstore search directly. But when searched from browser and pressing on install navigates to playstore and installs successfully. I am using a HP Slate 7 to install http://www.gsmarena.com/hp_slate_7-5317.php **

Answer (score 2):

I faced same thing while uploading. It

When I removed all the `uses-feature` block it started listing all mobiles and tablets. This is the manifest I have -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.COMPANY.APP.app">

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.COMPANY.APP.app.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.COMPANY.APP.app.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.COMPANY.APP.app.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"
        android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.HARDWARE_CONTROLS"
        android:protectionLevel="normal" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: Hey Jimit, The previous version used the same block and used to install in 7 inch tablets

Comment: I changed the uses feature android.hardware.location.gps to false and it doesn't appear in the playstore search directly. But when searched from browser and pressing on install navigates to playstore and installs successfully. I am using a HP Slate 7 to install

Comment: While uploading which all tablets where listed over there?

Comment: We do not have access to the dashboard sadly.